# How to mock the imported "package.json" in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

My React application refers `version` in the imported `package.json`.

```
import pjson from './package.json';

// snip

<p>Version: ${pjson.version}</p>
```

In the example above, [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) would display an error message like this:

```bash
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')

  69 |
> 70 |     <p>Version: v{pjson.version}</p>
     |                         ^
```

How can I mock this up?

Comment: Do you have an actual `package.json` file? Why do you want to mock it?

Comment: > Do you have an actual `package.json` file?
Yes.
> Why do you want to mock it?
Just because I want to control Jest errors...

Comment: You can create jest.config file and specific `moduleNameMapper` to stub out package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just importing with asterisks solved the problem.
Neither `mock` nor `moduleNameMapper` is needed.

- `src/App.tsx`

```
import * as pjson from './package.json';
```

Answer (score 0):

I made these files. But the same.

`jest.config.ts`:

```
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.json$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mock.json',
  },
};
```

`__mocks__/mock.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0"
}
```